# Why does Lightroom CC Library Module adds grain and/or texture to certain of my images that is not present in the Develop Module?

Tags: lightroom, photo-editing, troubleshooting, software, image-quality

I've seen a few posts about the lightroom Library Module having a change in colors from the Develop Module because of the different color space they use but in my case it's more a question of Noise and Grain/Texture and not for every image on top oh that.
I've tried updating my processor's pilotes because someone told me it could help but it didn't change the problem. The version of Lightroom Classic i'm using is the latest version.

Here are some screenshot examples of the differences between the two modules :

Notice that on the picture of the bare back of a man the Library Module added some faint vertical lines accross his back that are not present in the Develop Module, it's not obvious at a first glance but very noticeable if you've spent time working on a picture and end up with details you didn't plan on having on the final result!
The second image of a man looking to the right is identical but a lot of grain is added when switching back to the Library module, I would like not to have to gauge how much grain I should have to put in Dev Module to achieve the actual look I want later in Library ahaha

Been pulling my hair on this, any help is much appreciated!!
Cheers everyone :)

[image: PIC 1 LIBRARY MODULE]

[image: PIC 1 DEVELOP MODULE]

[image: PIC 2 LIBRARY MODULE]

[image: PIC 2 DEVELOP MODULE]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is probably the type of preview the library module is using.

The library module and the develop module do not use the same files unless you create and edit smart previews (or non-raw files). Only the develop module shows you your actual raw image with edits. You can get close to that for the other modules if you have LR create 1:1 previews, but they are slow to create and take a lot of extra room.

Also note that compression (smaller size viewing) can cause artifacts like banding (lines) in gradients/smooth tone areas to appear. But I've never heard of it causing noise... I would guess that's a low quality preview version of an added grain edit.

The answer is to only use the develop module for critical evaluation.